# Redirect output to file specified by variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, output

To keep it simple, at the top of my bash script is the following code

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#if no arguments passed
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    DEBUG='1>/dev/null'
else
    DEBUG='1>&1'
fi
```

Then throughout the rest of the script are calls like this

```bash
echo Doing something here! $DEBUG
```

The point being if someone calls the script without arguments (`./myScript.sh`) it wont echo anything.
But if they do pass in a parameter (`./myScript.sh whathaveyou`) the `echo` statements should work normally.

Unfortunately, however `echo Doing something here! $DEBUG` is being evaluated as

```bash
echo Doing something here! "1>&1"
```

instead of

```bash
echo Doing something here! 1>&1
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to make your command evaluate text data as command syntax, you can make a conditional function:

```
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
  report() {
    true
  }
else
  report() {
    echo "$@"
  }
fi
report "Doing something here!"
```

If you want to run generic commands instead of just printing things, you can similarly use

```
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
  report() {
    "$@" > /dev/null
  }
else
  report() {
    "$@"
  }
fi

report echo "Here are you files:"
report ls
```

To implement it exactly as you specified, you'd have to use `eval` which has a number of security issues and isn't as convenient.

Comment: So it's not possible? (well, without using `eval`) Thanks for an equally simple alternative!

Comment: Not as described, no. But there are plenty of alternatives, such as this one or writing all your debug info to fd 42 and conditionally redirect that.

Comment: yeah I was just asking in case someone comes here because of the title, and this work around isn't useful for them. I, myself, will be using your first example, definitely

Comment: You could always edit your question to say something like "Adding a verbose/debug mode to a script" :P

Comment: that other guy - big like to your solution.  Hashbrown - why not using eval? it's kind of panacea to many similar shell problems

Comment: eval is very easy to use wrong and very hard to use right. Simple things like `report echo "Hello $name"` either becomes a mess like `eval echo "Hello "$(printf '%q' "$name") $DEBUG` or open up for potential failures and security issues.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do:

```
#!/bin/bash

test -z "$1" && exec > dev/null
```

This will redirect the output of the script to the bit bucket if the first argument is empty or not passed.  All commands (unless redirected) will then discard their output.

Comment: Perhaps because this would also silence all other commands in the script

Comment: If the commands to be used as debug are selective: `if test -z "$1; then exec 3> /dev/null; else exec 3>&1; fi; ... debug-cmd >&3`

Comment: @Hashbrown, huh?  This does not re-evaluate anything. This only requires you to simplify the top portion of your code, but you've just selected a solution that requires you to modify your entire script and adds quite a bit of syntactic noise.  Perhaps you commented on the wrong solution?

Comment: sorry, yes, I mis-interpreted. In response to your answer; the reason I had done it this way was to make sure other echo lines would write normally. Only those denoted with $DEBUG would be moot under argumentless invokation

Answer (score 0):

I tend to do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# if $1 is not empty, set $enable_trace to 'true'
enable_trace=${1:+true}

function trace()
{
  if [ "$enable_trace" = 'true' ]; then
    echo "$@"
  fi
}

trace Doing something here
```

Introducing the $enable_trace parameter also allows you to turn the output on and off easily at different points within your script.